# How did Danny get to this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

> Danny has solved the inequality $x^3>3x^2-2x$.
>
> $$x^3>3x^2-2x$$
> $$x \times x^2 > x \times (3x-2)$$
> $$x^2 > 3x -2$$
> $$x^2 - 3x+2>0$$

Here comes the part I don't understand; he continues to this:

> $$(x-1)\times(x-2)>0$$
> $$x\in \langle\leftarrow, 1\rangle \cup \langle{2, \rightarrow\rangle}$$

I don't understand either of these. First of all, the part at the bottom is using notation I'm not familiar with, but I believe it may be the same as this:

$$x \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (2, \infty)$$

The uppermost part of the confusing bit is just confusing because I don't understand how he went from $x^2 - 3x+2>0$ to $(x-1)\times(x-2)>0$.

Comment: Sketch the actual interval testing graph. Also, who is danny?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Danny is just the name mentioned in the problem.

Comment: How can we write $ x \times x^2 > x \times (3x-2)$⇒$x^2 >3x-2$(this isn't true if $x$ is negative). One counter example is $ x=-1$.

Comment: @boojum thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: There is a typo in line four of the calculation: that should be $ \ x^2 -3x + 2 \ $.  The factorization is correct after that, though.  Before that, there is a mistake in canceling the factor of $ \ x \ $ in line three, since $ \ x  \ $ can be negative and will change the direction of the inequality.  It would be best to start with $ \ x · (x-1) · (x-2) \ > \ 0 \ \ $ and consider the _four_ implied intervals.

Comment: If you factor $x^2 -3x + 2$ you see $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x-2)(x-1)$.  And in order for $(x-2)\times (x-1)$ to be positive we must have both $x-2$ and $x-1$ be either both positive or both be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it we are supposed to critic Danny's work?  He made an error in assuming $x\times x^2 > x\times (3x-2) \to x^2 > 3x-2$.  That just isn't true. We can't divide by $x$ because we don't know if $x$ is positive, negative or $0$.  If $x$ is positive then $x A > x B \implies A > B$.  But if $x < 0$ then $xA > xB \implies A< B$.

What he needs to do is get everything to one side of an inequality.

$x^3>3x^2-2x$

$x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x > 0$ and then factor.

$x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x =$

$x(x^2 -3x +2) =$

$x(x-1)(x-2) > 0$.

(I'm not sure why you had difficulty seeing that $x^2 -3x + 2$ factors to $(x-1)(x-2)$.)

We have a product with three factors $x,x-1, x-2$.  For the product to be positive, (which is what $> 0$ implies) we must have either all of them positive.  Or an even number of them negative.  (A negative times a negative is a positive, but a negative times a positive is a negative.  So if you have an odd number of negatives the whole result is negative.  But if you have an even number of them negative they will multiply to a positive.)

Now $-2 < -1 < 0$ so $x-2 < x-1 < x$ so if they are all positive then we have $0 < x-2 < x- 1< x$ or in other words $0 < x-2$ or in other word $x -2 > 0$ and $x > 2$.

But if an even number of them are negative then $x-2 < x-1 < 0 < x$.

Or more simply $x -1 < 0$ and $0 < x$.

If $x -1 < 0$ then $x < 1$ and we have $0 < x < 1$.

So either $x > 2$ (and $x,x-1,x-2$ are all positive) or $0 < x < 1$ (and $x$ is positive but $x-1$ and $x-2$ is negative).

So the solution is $(0,1) \cup (2, \infty)$.

Comment: The issue OP had with that was that originally the quadratic had been typed as $ \ x^2 - 3x - 2 \ \ , $ which of course doesn't factor that way...

Comment: Oh... that had been editted by the time I saw it.

Comment: Given that there is no intersection between the set $(0,1)$ and the set $(2,\infty)$, wouldn't it be correct to rather say $x \in (0,1) \oplus (2,\infty)$? Having the union isn't incorrect, but the solution could be made more precise by replacing it with the exclusive or, no?